# On the pH scale, each unit change in pH represents a tenfold increase in acidity or alkalinity.

Tags: logarithms

Trying to solve similar type equation to this.

On the pH scale, each unit change in pH represents a tenfold increase in acidity or alkalinity. According to the diagram, vinegar is how many times as acidic as pure water?

[image]

Comment: Could you answer this if instead of $3.2$ it were $6$? $5$? $4$?

Comment: I don't know how to start can you show me?

Comment: Hint: note the replacement tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Each unit decrease in pH represents a tenfold increase in acidity. In other words the increase in acidity was:

$$10^{n-(n-1)}=10^{1}$$

Use some algebra to generalize this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put isn't it 10^(3.8) ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I think it would help if you could add more details as to why this is true and how you arrived at it. Just some friendly advice. Regards

Comment: I think that explaining where that $3.8$ came from would be sufficient in this case. New member or not :-) But also, Stephen, this is a serious concern among many members. Do try to make your answer useful to the original poster. The point in answering this kind of questions is usually not to show that you know how to solve it yourself, but to explain the thought process to the asker. I think you will quickly learn this kind of best practices! Welcome to MSE in spite of this mild criticism!

Comment: how di dyou get 3.8?

Answer (score 0):

pH represents the negative logrithm of H+ ions.  So the number ic $ln(c)/ln(0.1)$.

Acidity could then be written as $7-pH$ as a logrithm, or $10^{7-pH}$ as a number.

If you are using a different number system, the units are gram-moles per litre, and the adjustment to water is to add 3 to the pH, eg $pH_{12}=(pH_{10}+3)/log_{10}(12)$.  This would reference it to a 'water-mole', eg gram-mole / cc, where 'water' = 'gram/cc'.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. It would have 10^3.8 times more acidity. Or put another way, vinegar has 10^3.8 times as many free [H+] and [H3O+] ions in solution as pure water.

To get technical, it is actually -log(activity H+), where H+ per molecule of H20 is about 10^-7. Thus more strongly acidic solutions have a higher activity 10^-3.2 mol H+/mol H2O.